# AngularJS service function not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am working on Angular service. where I am getting error "TypeError: this.testTwoFunction is not a function" for function "testTwoFunction"

```
angular.module('MobileAppModule')
.run([‘MyService’, function(MyService)
{
    console.log("MyService in run");
    MyService.init();

}])
.service('MyService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{

    this.init = function() {
        testOneFunction();
    }
    function testOneFunction() {
        this. testTwoFunction()
    }

    this.testTwoFunction = function() {

    }

}]);
```

How do I call the function 'testTwoFunction()'

Comment: did you fix the space between "this" and "testTwoFunction()" ?

Comment: yes, but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to "hoisting".  TLDR: testOneFunction is a function declaration, while testTwoFunction is a function expression (or an anonymous function assigned to the variable "this.testTwoFunction").  In the given case you'll need to do a little re-ordering:

```
this.init = function() {
  testOneFunction();
};

this.testTwoFunction = function() {
  // doing something here
};

function testOneFunction() {
  this.testTwoFunction();
}
```

You can read more info about scoping and hoisting here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
(function () 
  {'use strict';
angular.module('MobileAppModule',[])
.run(['MyService', function(MyService)
 {
console.log("MyService in run");
MyService.init()}])
.service('MyService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
 {
var self = this;
self.init = function() {
    testOneFunction();
}
self.testTwoFunction = function() {
    console.log("severice 2")
}
function testOneFunction() {
    self.testTwoFunction();
}
}]);
 })();
```